# Github actions EACCES: permission denied on yarn install

Tags: github-actions

Can anyone please help me through this issue.
On App Deployment through Github actions I'm getting this error on building react app setction.

```
Run yarn build
yarn run v1.22.5
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/runner/work/COVID-19-Tracker-App/COVID-19-Tracker-App/node_modules/.cache'


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

My workflow contains this and I'm getting this error on "Build React App" section.

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: React App Deployment

# Controls when the action will run. Triggers the workflow on push or pull request
# events but only for the master branch
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Runs a single command using the runners shell
      - name: Install Node.Js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2-beta
        with:
          node-version: 12
      
      - name: Install Yarn
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
        with:
          cmd: install # will run `yarn install` command
          
      - name: Build React App
        run: yarn build
        
      - name: Install Surge
        run: npm install --global surge
        
      - name: Deploy to Surge
        run: surge ./build covid-19_tracker_app.surge.sh --token ${{secrets.Surge_Token}}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo yarn build`?

Answer (score 1):

You should follow that, use cmd not use run

```
name: CI
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
        with:
          cmd: install # will run `yarn install` command
      - uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
        with:
          cmd: build # will run `yarn build` command
```

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-for-yarn

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo yarn build` instead of `yarn build`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems in github actions, it turned out that some previous step caused a directory to be owned by the root user.

```bash
sudo chown $USER invoice-app/build
```

fixed it.

The [ssh debug action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/debugging-with-ssh) was super helpful in finding the problem, I highly recommend it if you're having these kinds of problems.